# Creating loop to parse table data in scrapy/python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

Have python script using scrapy , which scrapes the data from a website, allocates it to 3 fields and then generates a .csv. Works ok but with one major problem. All fields contain all of the data, rather than it being separated out for each table row. I'm sure this is due to my loop not working and when it finds the xpath it just grabs all the data for every row before moving on to get data for the other 2 fields, instead of creating seperate rows

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    divs = hxs.select('//tr[@class="someclass"]')
    for div in divs:
        item = TestBotItem()
        item['var1'] = div.select('//table/tbody/tr[*]/td[2]/p/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['var2'] = div.select('//table/tbody/tr[*]/td[3]/p/span[2]/text()').extract() 
        item['var3'] = div.select('//table/tbody/tr[*]/td[4]/p/text()').extract()
        return item
```

The tr with the * increases in number with each entry on the website I need to crawl, and the other two paths slot in below. How do I edit this so it grabs the first set of data for say //table/tbody/tr[3] only, stores it for all three fields and then moves on to //table/tbody/tr[4] etc??

**Update**

Works correctly, however I'm trying to add some validation to the pipelines.py file to drop any records where var1 is more than 100%. I'm certain my code below is wrong, and also does "yield" instead of "return" stop the pipeline being used?

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem 

class TestbotPipeline(object):
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if item('var1') > 100%:
        return item
    else: 
        raise Dropitem(item)
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    divs = hxs.select('//tr[@class="someclass"]')
    for div in divs:
        item = TestBotItem()
        item['var1'] = div.select('./td[2]/p/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['var2'] = div.select('./td[3]/p/span[2]/text()').extract() 
        item['var3'] = div.select('./td[4]/p/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

You loop on the `tr`s and then use relative XPath expressions (`./td...`), and in each iteration you use the `yield` instruction.

You can also append each item to a list and return that list **outside** of the loop) like this (it's equivalent to the code above):

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    divs = hxs.select('//tr[@class="someclass"]')
    items = []

    for div in divs:

        item = TestBotItem()
        item['var1'] = div.select('./td[2]/p/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['var2'] = div.select('./td[3]/p/span[2]/text()').extract() 
        item['var3'] = div.select('./td[4]/p/text()').extract()

        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Comment: if you could show me how to append to a list outside the loop that would help as I'm now trying to gather more data. I've tried to write some validation into the "pipelines.py" but it seems to ignore it and output all the data, even that which doesn't match the condition.

Comment: I updated my answer with a list of items returned outside of the loop. You should probably share you spider and pipeline code in some pastebin service for us to check. Also, inside the loop on `div`s, make sure you're using **relative XPath expressions**, e.g. `./td[2]/p/span[2]/text()` and **not absolute** ones like `//td[2]/p/span[2]/text()`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `HtmlXPathSelector`. Scrapy already has built-in XPATH selector. Try this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    divs = response.xpath('//tr[@class="someclass"]')
    for div in divs:
        item = TestBotItem()
        item['var1'] = div.xpath('table/tbody/tr[*]/td[2]/p/span[2]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['var2'] = div.xpath('table/tbody/tr[*]/td[3]/p/span[2]/text()').extract()[0] 
        item['var3'] = div.xpath('table/tbody/tr[*]/td[4]/p/text()').extract()[0]
        return item
```