# Python Scrapy grabbing table not working in the way it should

Tags: python, scrapy

Following the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105759/2378780) I have designed the scraper as follows:

```python
import scrapy

from lankatable.items import LankatableItem

class TableScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    """docstring for TableScraper."""
    name = "table"
    allowed_domains = ["lankabd.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://lankabd.com/dse/stock-market/GSPFINANCE/gsp-finance-company-(bangladesh)-limited-/financial-statements?companyId=300&stockId=287",
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        Item = LankatableItem()
        Item['industry'] = response.css('.portalTitleL2 ::text').extract_first().split(' - ')[-2]
        Item['ticker']   = response.css('.portalTitle.companyTitle ::text').extract_first().split(' (')[-1].strip(')')
        Item['yearEnd']  = response.css('.note>font::text').extract_first()
        # text in a row-cell
        Item['summery'] = {}
        for tr in response.xpath(".//*[@id='summery']/table/tbody/tr"):
            Item['summery']['title'] = tr.xpath('/td[1]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            Item['summery']['y2011'] = tr.xpath('/td[2]/span/text()').extract_first().strip()
            print Item
        print "Hello World!"
```

With the items as :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class LankatableItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    ticker   = scrapy.Field()
    industry = scrapy.Field()
    yearEnd  = scrapy.Field()
    summery  = scrapy.Field()   # should hold 'summery' table from the page
    balance  = scrapy.Field()   # should hold 'Balance-sheet' table from the page
    income   = scrapy.Field()   # should hold 'income-statemnt' table from the page
    cash     = scrapy.Field()   # should hold 'cash-flow' table from the page
```

But it is not grabbing anything. Don't understand what is missing in my code! Any help is highly appreciated. Since `response` includes the `Xpath` internally I'm not using the [HtmlXpathSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19708172/2378780) in my code.

And I ran it with `scrapy crawl table` in the root folder.

Comment: Have you tested your CSS and XPath with `scrapy shell` for example? Also,  for `tr.xpath('/td[1]/text()')`, you probably meant `tr.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')`, otherwise, you're searching for `td` elements at the root of the document, not relatively to the `tr` you're at in the loop. And you need to return (or yield) your item at the end of your `parse` callback method.

Comment: Be careful with `table/tbody/tr` parts in your XPaths. `tbody` elements are usually added by your browser (where you presumably tested your XPath), and not present in the original HTML source. Check [Caveats with inspecting the live browser DOM](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firefox.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom)

Comment: try it         `for tr in response.xpath("//*[@id='summery']/table/tbody/tr"):`

Comment: Hi @paultrmbrth, Thanks; yes it is the `tbody` element culprit that is stopping my way! Anyway, I still have more problems in getting where I have to go. Be back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of why your xpath doesn't work is becuase of `tbody`. You have to remove it and check if you get that result that you want.

You can read this in scrapy documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/firefox.html

> Firefox, in particular, is known for adding `<tbody>` elements to
>   tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page
>   HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use `<tbody>` in
>   your XPath expressions.